# Nodejs http.get(url[, options][, callback]) method type error while including options

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, http, get, alexa-skills-kit

I'm developing a simple chatbot on Amazon Alexa. The idea is to know if an item is on menu at a particular store.

```
function httpGet() {
  return new Promise(((resolve, reject) => {

      const options = {
          headers: {
              'auth_key':'xxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxx'
          }          
      };


    http.get("http://example.com/lookup/api/getitemlist?item=cake&storeid=50", options, (resp) => {       
        let data = '';      
        resp.on('data', (chunk) => {
            data += chunk;
        });

        resp.on('end', () => {            
            resolve(JSON.parse(data));
        });

        }).on('error', (err) => {
            reject(err);
        });

  }));
}
```

I'm following documentation on [nodejs docs](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_get_url_options_callback)

The API works well in postman where the auth_key is passed in header.

Here's the error from amazon cloudwatch[image: log]

The API responds with error message when the auth_key isnt present. Am I missing something? From reading the documentation. I thought this would work.

GetItemIntentHandler. I have to write more to handle the response. For now I'm only logging it. This is where I call the function httpGet();

```
const GetItemIntentHandler = {
    canHandle(handlerInput) {
        return Alexa.getRequestType(handlerInput.requestEnvelope) === 'IntentRequest'
            && Alexa.getIntentName(handlerInput.requestEnvelope) === 'GetItemIntent';
    },

    async handle(handlerInput){
      const item = handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.slots.Item.value;    

      const response = await httpGet();
      console.log("response reached us");
      console.log(response);
      return handlerInput.responseBuilder

            .speak(` ${item}`)
            .reprompt("What would you like?")
            .getResponse();

   }

};
```

Comment: I believe the problem is somewhere else. Post the code where you've created the server.

Comment: I'm using alexa developer console. On the code tab you can edit directly.

Answer (score 0):

I used the http.get(options[, callback]) method to get around. 
Updated httpGet function I'm using now.

```
function httpGet() {
  return new Promise(((resolve, reject) => {

      var options = {
          host: 'example.com',
          path: '/lookup/api/getitemlist?item=cake&storeid=50',
          port: null,
          headers: {
              'auth_key':'xxxxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxxxxxxx'
          }

      };



    http.get(options, (resp) => {

         let data = '';

        resp.on('data', (chunk) => {
            data += chunk;
        });

        resp.on('end', () => {

            resolve(JSON.parse(data));
        });

        }).on('error', (err) => {
            reject(err);
        });

  }));
}
```